# react-autocomplete multiple suggestions

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete

```
  const getSuggestions = value => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : _products.filter(lang =>
      lang.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
    );
  };
```

The current algorithm of react-autocomplete only finds the first word of a phase. 
For example I can only find "Coca Cola Zero Sugar Cola" when I write "coc" or"coca" but I cannot find it if I write "Cola", "Zero" or "Sugar". I asked in repo's issues but cannot get and answer. I tried myself without success.
How can I write algorithm that will work as I explained above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your filter to use [`.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of `===` it will return multiple suggestions:

```
const getSuggestions = value => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : _products.filter(lang =>
      lang.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue)
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This also does it

```
  const getSuggestions = value => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;
    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : _products.filter(lang =>
      lang.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
  };
```